# liberty redhat deployment not work

Tags: linux, websphere-liberty

I have a ear file running on my local windows 7/liberty j2ee7/Eclipse Mars without any issues. I am trying to deploy it to a liberty on docker. I got the error messages. Any suggestions?

> [AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
>
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKE0100I: This product is licensed for development, and limited production use. The full license terms can be viewed here: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/license/base_ilan/ilan/16.0.0.3/lafiles/en.html
>
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKG0093A: Processing configuration drop-ins resource: /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/configDropins/defaults/keystore.xml
>
> [WARNING ] CWWKS3103W: There are no users defined for the BasicRegistry configuration of ID com.ibm.ws.security.registry.basic.config[basic].
>
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKS4104A: LTPA keys created in 3.308 seconds. LTPA key file: /opt/ibm/wlp/output/defaultServer/resources/security/ltpa.keys
>
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications.
>
> [AUDIT   ] CWPKI0803A: SSL certificate created in 4.004 seconds. SSL key file: /opt/ibm/wlp/output/defaultServer/resources/security/key.jks
>
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKI0001I: The CORBA name server is now available at corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2809/NameService.
>
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0012I: The application csxstartershowcaseEAR was not started.
>
> **[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0124E: Application csxstartershowcaseEAR does not contain any modules.**
>
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [servlet-3.1, beanValidation-1.1, ssl-1.0, jndi-1.0, jca-1.7, ejbPersistentTimer-3.2, appSecurity-2.0, j2eeManagement-1.1, jdbc-4.1, wasJmsServer-1.0, jaxrs-2.0, javaMail-1.5, cdi-1.2, webProfile-7.0, jcaInboundSecurity-1.0, jpa-2.1, jsp-2.3, ejbLite-3.2, managedBeans-1.0, jsf-2.2, ejbHome-3.2, jaxws-2.2, localConnector-1.0, jsonp-1.0, el-3.0, jaxrsClient-2.0, concurrent-1.0, appClientSupport-1.0, ejbRemote-3.2, javaee-7.0, jaxb-2.2, mdb-3.2, jacc-1.5, batch-1.0, ejb-3.2, json-1.0, jaspic-1.1, distributedMap-1.0, websocket-1.1, wasJmsSecurity-1.0, wasJmsClient-2.0].
>
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server defaultServer is ready to run a smarter planet.

My server.xml is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="Default server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>


    <basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm"> 
        <!-- <user name="yourUserName" password="" />  --> 
    </basicRegistry>
    
    <!-- To allow access to this server from a remote client host="*" has been added to the following element -->
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  host="*"
          httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" />
                  
    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
    
         <!-- Datasource -->
     <library id="derbyLibrary">
           <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/derby" id="shared.resource.dir..derby"/>
     </library>
     <jdbcDriver javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedConnectionPoolDataSource40" javax.sql.DataSource="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource" javax.sql.XADataSource="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedXADataSource40" libraryRef="derbyLibrary">
     </jdbcDriver>
  
     <!-- Application -->
     <enterpriseApplication id="aEAR" name="aEAR">
           <classloader commonLibraryRef="derbyLibrary"></classloader>
     </enterpriseApplication>

</server>
```

Comment: In Docker, depending how you are deploying your app you may have issues with auto expanding. Try to set `applicationManager autoExpand="false"`. Or deploy for example from Eclipse - the latest WebSphere Developer Tools have Docker support and you can deploy directly to Docker container.

Comment: @Gas tried autoExpand="false" not work.

Comment: My application needs EJB, JAXWS. Do I need to put them into the feature manager in the server.xml?  I didn't have to do it in the local.

Comment: No, if you have `javaee-7.0` feature then you will have these features enabled implicitly. So what docker image are you using and how are you deploying your app there?

Comment: I used this command to download the latest and greatest full j2ee7 liberty. **docker pull websphere-liberty**.  I then copy the ear into the **/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/dropins/** in the Dockerfile along with the server.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. I used the Oracle JRE to build and run the ear in the Eclipse. When I switched to the IBM JRE to build the EAR, it works on the docker liberty. (The error message on the docker liberty is clueless.)

Comment: every message regarding anything IBM is clueless